# How to rewrite file content with inline Guard (gem), avoiding infinite loop

Tags: ruby, guard

How can I avoid an infinite loop with this kind of code?
(Rubocop's auto-correct does re-write files, although with a `system` command I think)

```
require 'guard/compat/plugin'

module ::Guard
  class RubyHtmlSyntaxFixer < Plugin
    def run_on_modifications(paths)
      paths.each do |path|
        text = File.read(path)
        text.gsub!('replace text', 'with something cool')
        File.open(path, 'w') {|file| file.puts text }
      end
    end
  end
end


guard 'ruby_html_syntax_fixer' do
  watch(%r{app/views/.+\.(erb|haml|slim)})
end
```